# Пользовательские стили для сайта

Tags: php, css

Подскажите логику мышления - допустим я хочу сделать в админке сайта что бы пользователь мог менять сам фон (`$fon`). Я соеденяюсь с базой (?) для хранения значения переменной, затем задаю ей значение по умолчанию (#000). После чего человек заходит в админку и может менять фон сайта - но как мне задать стили этой переменной т.е. например

```
html, body {background: #000;}
```

Так собственно вопрос-как мне подставить переменную $fon вместо #000?

Answer (score 1):

Всё зависит от структуры Вашего сайта.

На одном из своих сайтов шаблонизатору в шаблон head отправлялась переменная background. Переменная создавалась на основе настроек сайта ( требовалось впихивать фоном рекламу как на кинопоиске). В самом шаблоне были строки:
    <style>
    background-image:url({background});
    </style>

Так как Вам требуется выдавать фон по настройкам пользователя могу предложить создать таблицу в бд с полями userID и background. 
Для выставления фона потребуется выяснять существует ли SESSION['userID'] если есть то проверять существует ли запись в БД , если есть выводим установленный пользователем фон если нету то используем стандартный.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать jquery - $('body').css('background-color', '#000 !important');

Comment: а на пхп нет способа сделать такую штуку?